# Docpad server not responding

Tags: node.js, docpad

I'm running a docpad instance, and it has been working just fine. Suddenly, now when I run `docpad watch`, the server starts alright and there are no error messages, but when I load `http://localhost:9778`, the site is not available. No errors appear in the console either, or at the command line. Anyone have any ideas about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Have you had a look at this page: http://docpad.org/docs/troubleshoot. It seems to say there is a problem with watch. Does "docpad run" work? What OS are you on?

Comment: This problem is occurring both on a MAC OS (10.9.4) and on my Ubuntu computer (14.10). I looked over that page, but didn't see anything particularly relevant.

Comment: I tried `docpad run` and it works fine. So the problem does seem to be with `docpad watch`, but nothing on the trouble shooting page seems to help.

Comment: I then need to ask the question, what are you trying to achieve with "docpad watch"? The trouble shooting page does have a couple of entries about "watch", mostly saying that it doesn't work. You're not on Windows, so its not a Windows quirk. Above that, I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you without more details. :)

Comment: I don't read the comments in the troubleshooting doc the way you do. They simply say that the watch mechanisms sometimes doesn't work. But that's not the difficulty I am experiencing. The watch works alright: changes are registered and regeneration occurs. The problem is that the website isn't served. :( I've added an issue in docpad's github account with more details: https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/881

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently and was able to get things rolling by adding `watchFile` to the `preferredMethods` in the docpad config - like so:

```
# git diff 
--- a/docpad.coffee
+++ b/docpad.coffee
@@ -23,5 +23,6 @@ docpadConfig =
   templateData: fetchConfig()
   watchOptions:
     catchupDelay: 0
+    preferredMethods: ['watchFile','watch']
```

It's mentioned in the [Docpad Troublshooting](https://docpad.org/docs/troubleshoot)
Hope this helps someone else.

UPDATE:  I've now seen this on a co-workers machine and this did *not* solve the issue.  It seems the server is just not responding.  Running under debug mode, all *looks* ok, but when I try to hit it (with curl) I get

Recv failure: Connection reset by peer.

UPDATE2:  After a bunch of tries, (reinstalling docpad and restarting things), this same fix seemed to work.  What we found was that watch would *appear* to run but and would see files change, but wasn't actually updating things in the `out` directory.  By adding the `watchFile` to `preferredMethods`, things seemed a bit less flaky.

It's weird to because the original config was working for a while (a week of development) with no issues.  But today it started being flaky on 2 separate dev environments.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have run with here is simply to use `docpad run`, which I think is the best practice. See [this discussion](https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/881) for more information.